# How to disable inserting empty line on paste?

Tags: intellij-idea

Each time I paste a line of code in IntelliJ IDEA it inserts an empty line below the inserted one, how to disable this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That empty line isn't being added by IDEA, it's already included in the selection. Basically you can avoid this by putting the end point of your selection at the last character and not below the block you're selecting.

Figure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWlY8.png